# Consuming real-time traffic data from Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, google, traffic

In order to microprocess an logistic study about the best path to take, I need to consume, somehow, real-time traffic data from Google Maps.

Is there an "open source" way to do this?

The application I'm intending to develop will start an process to consume real-time traffic data from this source, georeference the data needed for that path coordinates and then calculate, among other variables, the best path to take.

Comment: At the moment you have only told us what you want to do and nothing about where you have already looked for an answer. You seem to be seeking a software recommendation for which there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks PolyGeo. I will look a bit deeper about what I need, since I don't think I need a software. What I really need is to access the real-time traffic database, from, preferentially, Google Maps, all in a free way. This is a personal project, not bussiness, and my focus is to calculate lots of variables about traffic, in order to show the best path. Variables: GPS data (in vehicles), estimated time for a complete or partial path (in sec per kilometer), local traffic sensors, among other "smartcity" sensors. Again, thanks for your time. I (or you) will delete this question.

Comment: I think you are looking for an open API to Google traffic Infomation.

Comment: Yes! For it's DB.

Comment: I am looking all the answears on this topic (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600656/access-googles-traffic-data-through-a-web-service)... one by one.